# Visibility in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I need to show the following in my report

**A**       B     C    D
  A data

```
A     **B**    C    D
```

B data

Here,  'A,B,C,D' are the headers inside a text box or table header.
When I click on A, A's data need to be displayed

When I click on B, A's data should be hidden and only B's data should be displayed in the same place where A's data was shown earlier. Likewise for C and D.

How is this possible?
Help needed ASAP.!!
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Iswarya

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend Reporting Services for this sort of interactivity. Reporting Services helps with the delivery of more static displays of data, handling formatting and delivery to different formats. Are you tied to SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a parameter to accept your A,B,C,D values and pass them to your dataset (WHERE clause or Filter). Then you need to add an Action to your text box headers.  The Action will be to "Go to report".  Specify the current report. Add the parameter created above and hard code the value as appropriate - meaning for the text box heading that shows: A, the Parameter should be passed the value: A, etc.